# Ссылка на объект Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
    var home = new Vue({
      el: '#user-home',
      data: {
            drafts:{},
            progress:false
      },
      methods:{
          get_drafts:function (){
               firebase.database().ref('drafts/')
                .orderByChild('user').equalTo(user_data.uid)
                .on('value', function(snapshot) { 
                     this.drafts =  snapshot.val();
                     //Здесь у меня проблема
                });

          }
      }

});
```

Не могу внутри функции `function(snapshot)` получить доступ к drafts. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Стрелочную функцию используйте. `.on('value', snapshot => this.drafts =  snapshot.val());`

Comment: Спасибо..........